# Making a string print out on list instead of integer

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
from random import shuffle
x = [[i] for i in range(10)]
shuffle(x)
```

Am trying to make a basic memory game on python. Above is my current code to generate random numbers in a list but I want it to print out a string instead of an integer e.g. 'duck' instead of #5 every time it is printed. When I input something like:

```
print(x[4])
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `duck` instead of `5`, and what instead of `7`, `2` or `3` for example?

Comment: Do you have your list of string elements or you want a generic approach ?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to put all of your options in a list and then use [`random.suffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle the contents in-place. If you don't want to modify your original list, be sure to make a copy first.

```
items = ['duck', 'goose', 'swan']
random.shuffle(items)

# ['goose', 'duck', 'swan']
```

If you really need to keep track of where they came from (i.e. their original index), you can use a tuple to hold your items *and* their original index and then shuffle that.

```
tupled_items = [x for x in enumerate(items)]
random.shuffle(tupled_items)

# [(1, 'goose'), (0, 'duck'), (2, 'swan')]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use some package to generate random words for example
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RandomWords/0.1.5
and then do something like

```
from random_words import RandomWords
rw = RandomWords()
x = [rw.random_word() for _ in range(10)]
print x
```

If you already know words you want to use, make it as a dict, and do something like this [Randomly shuffling a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895028/randomly-shuffling-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic answer for a list of strings then follow the below code :-

```
from random import shuffle
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = shuffle(string_list)
print(string_list)
```