# How do I shuffle the words that are connected to a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, shuffle

I have a dictionary

```
GiftDict = {'Seth':'A', 'Jeremy':'B', 'Ben':'C'}
```

I want to shuffle the values in this dictionary to different keys.
I tried splitting the dictionary into two like this...

```
person = GiftDict.keys()
partner = GiftDict.values()
```

And shuffling the values with

```
import random    
random.shuffle(partner)
```

But I keep getting a type error:'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

I want to recreate the dictionary but with shuffled values. Is this the correct way to get there?
Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot shuffle collections such as `dict_values` (the result of dict.values()), which have no order - they cannot be subscripted by `coll[i]`. You need an ordered collection, such as a `list`. Try calling `partner = list(partner)` before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895325/9477227) you can't reshuffle a dictionary. However, you can create a list of the dictionary's values, shuffle that, and then create a new dictionary with the same keys and updated values.

```py
import random

original = {'Seth':'A', 'Jeremy':'B', 'Ben':'C'}
result = {'Seth':'A', 'Jeremy':'B', 'Ben':'C'}
values = list(original.values())

# Shuffle values 
random.shuffle(values)

# Set values back into the result dictionary
for i,j in enumerate(original.keys()):
    result[j] = values[i]

# Now the result dictionary contains the original keys and updated values
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If youre using a Python version < 3.7 Python dicts have no order so shuffeling is pointless.
If youre on a newer Python version you may shuffle the dicts items like below.

```
import random
l = list(GiftDict.items())
random.shuffle(l)
shuffled_dict = dict(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the method `dict.values()` returns an object of type `dict_values` which is not subscriptable. You can cast it to a list, but it won't help to shuffle it like this.

You can instead use this function to shuffle a dict :

```
import random
def shuffle_dict(dic):
    new_values = list(dic.values())
    random.shuffle(new_values)
    return dict(zip(dic.keys(), new_values))
```

Now:

```
shuffle_dict(GiftDict)
# > {'Seth': 'B', 'Jeremy': 'C', 'Ben': 'A'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
import random    
random.shuffle(list(partner)) # GiftDict.values() can not be shuffled as such, it needs to be converted as list
```

A full example:

```
import random

d = {'Seth':'A', 'Jeremy':'B', 'Ben':'C'}

v = list(d.values())

random.shuffle(v)

for i,k in enumerate(d.keys()):
    d[k] = v[i]

print (d)
```

Output:

```
{'Seth': 'B', 'Jeremy': 'A', 'Ben': 'C'}
```